How can a field be rendered as floating field using crisy_forms+crispy_boostrap5 filter only?
I have a form where there is a field 'username' and some other fields. I want to render this field as Bootstrap5 floating field, and want to do so only using crispy filter. I have currently done like this:
# Django form
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
  # some declarations
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = CrispyFormHelper(
      self,
      form_action='my_app:sign_in',
      layout=Layout(
        FloatingField('username'),
        Field('password'),
        Submit('submit', 'Sign in'),
      )
    )

<!-- template -->
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}  <!-- does not render floating -->

I checked as_crispy_field filter, haven't found anything useful that can be passed to tell it to render it as floating.
So how do I do this?
